# c# setting the bytes to read threshold

Tags: c#, serial-port

Does setting the `serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 64;`only affect when the bytes received event fires. Right now I am using a timer and `serialPort1.Read(temp, 0, bytestoread);`., and I am not using the bytes received event. Will setting the received bytes threshold affect this.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //creates a timer tick event to read everything in the port when the timer ticks
    {

        int bytestoread = 0;

        timer1.Stop();
        try
        {
            bytestoread = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Serial connection lost. Exception types:" + ex.ToString());
        }
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            if(bytestoread != 0)
            {
                byte[] temp = new byte[bytestoread];
                serialPort1.Read(temp, 0, bytestoread);
                if(firstRead && (temp[0] == 0xC0 && temp[1] == 0x04 && temp[2] == 0xC0))
                {
                    serialPort1.Write(packageToSend, 0, packageToSend.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    tempBuffer.AddRange(temp);
                    firstRead = false;
                    btnIndicator.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }                    
            }
        }
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specfic? What type is `serialPort1`? Can you post a more extensive code sample so we can tell what is going on?

Comment: serialPort1 is a serial port used to read in data

Comment: Right, I assumed it was type `SerialPort` but can you post a more extensive code sample for context?

Comment: gotcha. I added the code I am using. So basically every 10 ms every thing that is in the serial port should be read. That appears to be what is happening, and everything functions like I expect. However I do not know if I should be messing with the default read threshold of one, or that even affects anything going on in my code. I open the serial part in another section of code, and that where I would change the default read threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted, I do not see how the `SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold` property would affect your code. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold?view=netframework-4.7.1) is the documentation from the .NET library. It says it controls the "number of bytes in the internal input buffer before a `DataReceived` event occurs." The default value is 1. Since you are not handling the `DataReceived` event in the code you posted, changing this will have no effect on the overall execution.

The use case for this would be if you had an event handler for this event and wanted to only have it trigger when a certain number of bytes are available.